# Guardar variable $_POST al hacer click en una imagen

Tags: php, imagen

Tengo el siguiente bucle que visualiza las carpetas que hay en una ubicación predeterminada.

```
 while ($fil = readdir($carpeta)) {
        if (is_dir($ruta . $fil) && $fil != "." && $fil != "..") {
            echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 work-item'>";
            echo "<a href='/BotigaVirtual/codiFont/vistaFotosAlbum.php/?album=" . $this->ruta . $fil . "'> <img src='../codiFont/images/fotoAlbum.jpg'";
            echo "class='img-responsive' class='fh5co-work-title'>";
            echo "<h4>" . $fil . "</h4>";
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
```

Necesito hacer que al hacer click en la foto de la ubicación, vaya a otra pagina y les pase un parámetro $_POST[] para poder imprimirlo en esa pantalla.
Lo he intentado con $_GET pero me gustaría más hacerlo utilizando $_POST.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: podes usar radio buttons ocultos con un label asociado que contiene la imagen ver ejemplo en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/203046/81450

Comment: Hola, Me puedes dar ejemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ejemplo del enlace es por si hay que seleccionar y luego enviar el formulario, para que el envío sea al hacer click en la imagen podes usar `buttons` sin estilos, algo así:

```
<?php
$ruta = __DIR__. '/images/';
$carpeta = opendir($ruta);
?>
<form action="vistaFotosAlbum.php" method="post">
  <?php
  while ($fil = readdir($carpeta)) :
    if (is_dir($ruta . $fil) && $fil != "." && $fil != "..") :
      ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 work-item">
        <button
          name="album"
          value="<?php echo $ruta . $fil ?>"
          style="background:none;border:medium none;cursor:pointer;"
        >
        <img
        src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/janosch500/tropical-waters-folders/256/Applications-icon.png"
        class="img-responsive fh5co-work-title"
        width="32" height="32"
        >
        <h4><?php echo $fil;?></h4>
      </button>
    </div>
    <?php
  endif;
endwhile;
?>
</form>
```